# Flutter App Build Issue after updating to 3.10 with Gesture Detectors

Tags: flutter

After updating from 3.7 to 3.10 I am receiving build issues that appear to be related to Gesture Detectors.

Trace output(https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Uwi.png)

This is an added package of course and when I look at the code is it complains about this

`

```
TextSelectionGestureDetector buildGestureDetector({
    Key? key,
    HitTestBehavior? behavior,
    required Widget child,
  }) =>
      TextSelectionGestureDetector(
        key: key,
        onTapDown: onTapDown,
        onForcePressStart:
            delegate.forcePressEnabled ? onForcePressStart : null,
        onForcePressEnd: delegate.forcePressEnabled ? onForcePressEnd : null,
        onSingleTapUp: onSingleTapUp,
        onSingleTapCancel: onSingleTapCancel,
        onSingleLongTapStart: onSingleLongTapStart,
        onSingleLongTapMoveUpdate: onSingleLongTapMoveUpdate,
        onSingleLongTapEnd: onSingleLongTapEnd,
        onDoubleTapDown: onDoubleTapDown,
        onDragSelectionStart: onDragSelectionStart,
        onDragSelectionUpdate: onDragSelectionUpdate,
        onDragSelectionEnd: onDragSelectionEnd,
        behavior: behavior,
        child: child,
      );`
```

I also had an issue with accentColor in another package but I was able to resolve that by editing it (even though it was a pub package and not my code). There is no mention of this in breaking changes though.

Has anyone seen this before and is there a solution?

Cheers,

I have tried the following

- flutter clean
- flutter pub upgrade
- flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
- flutter create

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the problem causing the error was related to the package `flutter_math_fork 0.5.0`. Check your `pubspec.yaml` file for any packages that may be dependent on `flutter_math_fork 0.5.0`. You can refer to the list of packages that depend on flutter_math_fork [here](https://pub.dev/packages?q=dependency%3Aflutter_math_fork).

In my case, the `flutter_html` package was the culprit. Once I removed it from my `pubspec.yaml` file, the app ran successfully. It's unclear at this time whether the responsibility for fixing this issue lies with the `flutter_html` maintainer or with the **Flutter** team itself.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to have another go at upgrading in the next week, I actually reverted back to 3.7 to get it back up and running, But thanks heaps for the recommendation. I will let you know how I go to confirm the solution